# Abelianization of the group of invertible elements in a finite local ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $R$ be a finite local $\mathbb{F}_q$-algebra. Assume that $R\cong R^*$ as left $R$-modules. Are there any known results about the abelianization $(R^{\times})_{\mathrm{ab}}$?

(We can factor $R$ be the ideal $I$ generated by all additive commutators $xy-yx$. We then get a map $(R^{\times})_{\mathrm{ab}}\to (R/I)^{\times}$ but this map does not have to be an isomorphism).

Comment: Just to check notation, is $R^*$ the dual $\operatorname{Hom}(R, \mathbb F_q)$?

Comment: Yes indeed. I know that the socle of $R$ as a left $R$-module is one dimensional, and that enables me to derive such an isomorphism.